# QlikView Problems with Listbox

Tags: qlikview

I want to have a list box that shows the following:
`YYYY: WeekNumber - Date`

The `Date` part is using a Broadcast Calendar (starts on Sundays, so week 1 of 2012 is actually Monday `12/26/2011`).

This needs to be conditional:

- If the year selected is the current year, only show through the latest "broadcastMonday" which in this case is Week 9 (`2/20/2012`). Then go back all the way through the prior year to week 1 of 2011, which is actually `12/27/2010`.
- If the year selected is less than the current year, only show all of that year plus all of the prior year.

The following expression for the List Box is working just fine for me with respect to displaying the right information, but when I click an item in the list it doesn't select it:

```
=If([Year]=year(ReloadTime()),if(left(BroadcastPeriod2,4)>=[Prior Year]
and BroadcastWeekStart2<ReloadTime(),(left(BroadcastPeriod2,4) & ' : ' & 
BroadCastWeek2 & '-' & date(BroadcastWeekStart2)),),if(left(BroadcastPeriod2,4)>=
[Prior Year] and left(BroadcastPeriod2,4)<=([Year]),left(BroadcastPeriod2,4) & ' : '
& BroadCastWeek2 & '-' & date(BroadcastWeekStart2),))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is to either do it in the load (concatenating the fields) or to use a table instead of the input box.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to calculate the value for the listbox in the loadscript. I had trouble comparing StartMonth values in set analysis and could come around this by pre-calculating the values at load time.

Did something similar in [Qlikview aggration with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821517/qlikview-aggration-with-conditions/18848305#18848305)